# Is there a way to get 100% correct file extension in Android with scoped storage enabled?

Tags: android, file, mime-types, storage-access-framework, scoped-storage

I'm trying to implement a file sending functionality in my Android app (any files are allowed, and the files don't belong to my app). From the `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` I receive an `InputStream`, then I make a temp `File` object with the name I'm getting from `ContentResolver`'s `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME`, and then send the file. The reason I do all of this is that I work with a 3rd party API which allows for `File` objects only.

But the `OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME` doesn't guarantee that I get the file name with a file extension as stated in the [docs](https://developer.android.com/training/data-storage/shared/documents-files#examine-metadata). As far as I understand, there is no way to get the actual filename or physical path of a file with the [Scoped Storage](https://developer.android.com/preview/privacy/storage) enforced in the newer versions of Android. Therefore, I have to check if a filename contains an extension, and if not - get the file's MIME type with `ContentResolver` and the most common extension for it using the [MimeTypeMap](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/webkit/MimeTypeMap). This approach feels to be not very reliable since I have to rely on both `ContentResolver` correctly determining the MIME type and `MimeTypeMap` retrieving the correct extension. Getting the extension is crucial at least because users should be able to download and open files on their PC from a desktop app.

So, is it possible to get a filename or at least file extension with a 100% guarantee with scoped storage enabled? Or maybe is there a more efficient way to handle my situation? I'd appreciate some help with this.

Comment: What should this have to do with scoped storage? OPEN_DOCUMENT_FILE is much longer here.

Comment: @blackapps I mean that without scoped storage, I'd be able to retrieve a file path quite easily, and from there simply get a file extension (I'd be able to access files without SAF). Unfortunately, I'm not aware of what `OPEN_DOCUMENT_FILE` is.

Comment: Did you ever get a DISPLAY_NAME that was not the filename?

Comment: @blackapps no, I'm pretty new to Android development, so I don't know how often it can occur (although I think it's a rare situation). But as stated in the docs, it could happen, so my question is about being as safe as possible.

Comment: If the user chooses a file from internal memory or removable sd card or Downloads folder DISPLAY_NAME is always the filename. Maybe if a file -or just content- from another provider is choosed that it can happen. But i would not bother.

Comment: @V1raNi did you got any solution. I stuck into the same problem, for some files I'm only getting file name without extension.

Comment: @Shubham not really, was using the `DISPLAY_NAME` and then in case of missing extension applied a somewhat ugly hack that gets a file type from `ContentResolver.getType(uri)` and then gets the approximate extension with `MimeTypeMap.getSingleton().getExtensionFromMimeType(fileType)` (because the requirements were to have an extension 100% of the time). Maybe your files simply don't have one?

Comment: @V1raNi I also did the same but, still not getting the extension for multimedia files (having type application/octet-stream)

Answer (score 0):

Try this method, it helped me:

```
public static String getFileName(Uri uri, Context context) {
    String result = null;
    if (uri.getScheme().equals("content")) {
        Cursor cursor = context.getContentResolver().query(uri, null, null, null, null);
        try {
            if (cursor != null && cursor.moveToFirst()) {
                result = cursor.getString(cursor.getColumnIndex(OpenableColumns.DISPLAY_NAME));
            }
        } finally {
            cursor.close();
        }
    }
    if (result == null) {
        result = uri.getPath();
        int cut = result.lastIndexOf('/');
        if (cut != -1) {
            result = result.substring(cut + 1);
        }
    }
    return result;
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your input, but I thought that `ACTION_OPEN_DOCUMENT` returns only a `content://` URI, and its `DISPLAY_NAME` isn't necessarily a filename with an extension.

Comment: I used it for a while, and it gets the name with extension "file.pdf" exactly.